# save path and count images in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm able to scan directory of files uploaded to server via FTP

Now I want to discard the empty arrays and add path and total count of images into MySQL database. I will use that path and count of images to use them in HTML player and run these pictures as video.

Here is my code:

```
 <?php
$path = '/home/zackpc/usr/share/zoneminder/www/events/1';
// an unsorted array of dirs & files
$files_dirs = iterator_to_array( new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path),RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) );

echo '<html><body><pre>';
// create a new associative multi-dimensional array with dirs as keys and their files
$dirs_files = array();
foreach($files_dirs as $dir){
 if(is_dir($dir) AND preg_match('/\/\.$/',$dir)){
  $d = preg_replace('/\/\.$/','',$dir);
  $dirs_files[$d] = array();
  foreach($files_dirs as $file){
   if(is_file($file) AND $d == dirname($file)){
    $f = basename($file);
    $dirs_files[$d][] = $f;
   }
  }
 }
}
print_r($dirs_files);
echo '</pre></body></html>';

?>
```

I am getting following output:

```
[/home/zackpc/usr/share/zoneminder/www/events/1/18/08/06/14] => Array
        (
        )

[/home/zackpc/usr/share/zoneminder/www/events/1/18/08/06] => Array
    (
    )

[/home/zackpc/usr/share/zoneminder/www/events/1/18/08/06/11/21/28] => Array
    (
        [0] => 00020-capture.jpg
        [1] => 00043-capture.jpg
        [2] => 00006-capture.jpg
        [3] => 00008-capture.jpg
        [4] => 00049-capture.jpg
        [5] => 00007-capture.jpg
        [6] => 00013-capture.jpg
        [7] => 00025-capture.jpg
        [8] => 00016-capture.jpg
        [9] => 00033-capture.jpg
        [10] => 00051-capture.jpg
        [11] => 00014-capture.jpg
        [12] => 00044-capture.jpg
        [13] => 00001-capture.jpg
        [14] => 00035-capture.jpg
        [15] => 00039-capture.jpg
        [16] => 00048-capture.jpg
        [17] => 00009-capture.jpg
        [18] => 00022-capture.jpg
        [19] => 00034-capture.jpg
        [20] => 00024-capture.jpg
        [21] => 00041-capture.jpg
        [22] => 00002-capture.jpg
        [23] => 00029-capture.jpg
        [24] => 00023-capture.jpg
        [25] => 00010-capture.jpg
        [26] => 00038-capture.jpg
        [27] => 00003-capture.jpg
        [28] => 00017-capture.jpg
        [29] => 00047-capture.jpg
        [30] => 00015-capture.jpg
        [31] => 00012-capture.jpg
        [32] => 00005-capture.jpg
     )
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't tried anything.  The tasks that you need are, individually, mega-duplicates on this site.  Please research and attempt to self-solve before posting. P.s., you only need one `preg_` call per iteration. There is no `mysql` in this question, please tag appropriately.

Comment: Simply don't generate empty arrays with: `$dirs_files[$d] = array();`  What is your exact expected result?

Comment: @mickmackusa array with jpg files is my complete result i just want to save it in mysql database like "path  =  /home/zackpc/usr/share/zoneminder/www/events/1/18/08/06/11/21/28 " and " Image count =  33"

Comment: So you don't actually need to store the jpg name? Then dont.  Just increment a counter for each folder containing 1 or more images.

Answer (score 0):

Only loop once.  Only store what you need: paths and image counts.

```
foreach($files_dirs as $file){
    if (is_file($file)) {
        $d = dirname($file);
        if (!isset($dirs_files[$d])) {
            $dirs_files[$d] = 0;
        } else {
            ++$dirs_files[$d];
        }
    }
}
```

I've got to say:

1. I got lost in your code.
2. I did not test my answer, so no guarantees that it is perfect.